# Js regexp variable to get all matches in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, pug

There is the following code:

```
s.match(/\+[A-Za-z0-9_]+/);
```

I use it to get all Jade mixins from string. It works good for one Jade mixins in string ("+article"), but doesn't work for 2 mixins in string("+article +b") - it returns array with first item only. What did I do wrong? Thanks! Also it will be good to get array with values without plus!

Comment: `s.match(/\+[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g);` , add global flag `g`

Answer (score 0):

Add global flag `g` in your regex

```
s.match(/\+[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g);
```

---

**UPDATE :** Demo with removed `+` symbol

```js
s = '+abc +4kk +ttt';
var res = s.match(/\+[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g).map(function(v) {
  return v.substring(1) // get string after `+`
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

Or regex with captured group

```js
var s = '+abc +4kk +ttt';
var reg = /\+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/g;

var matches, res = [];
while (matches = reg.exec(s)) {
  res.push(matches[1]); // get captured group value
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Also, can I get array with values without plus?

Comment: @PranavCBalan Or [`\+(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/sW2tB3/1) and getting first captured group.

Comment: @Tushar : but he needs global match